# How to read values in XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have basic VB programming knowledge. I'm having trouble getting info from an XML file. I know I can simply open the XML as a normal file, and read it sequentially, but I'd like to have my code running as efficient as possible.

I'm reading a bunch of XML files. The `<full path>+<file name>` will be passed to the xml-reading sub or function.

Here's what the XML looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <mproxyMessage xmlns:ns2="com.cmp.mproxy.message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:mproxyMessage">
    <version>2</version>
    <receiver>
        <uid>az.local</uid>
    </receiver>
    <sender>
        <uid>test.sender</uid>
    </sender>
    <attachments>
        <attachment>
            <uri>C:\Inbox\2015-09-04\2cc403ace4984782bf5ae949e22a4d5b\VJ14699062340.ima</uri>
        </attachment>
    </attachments>
    <option>
        <map>
            <element>
                <key>OPTION_MEXI_OPTION</key>
                <value>DSUBJECT(DMA-IMA)DGIVENNAME(9803375)DSENDERID(144796) medidoc_formatrecipient : Demo User, 14699062,Department,AZO(recipient DN : uid=demo.user,null)</value>
            </element>
            <element>
                <key>DSENDERID</key>
                <value>144796</value>
            </element>
            <element>
                <key>DGIVENNAME</key>
                <value>9803375</value>
            </element>
            <element>
                <key>OPTION_MESSAGE_UID</key>
                <value>2cc403ace4984782bf5ae949e22a4d5b</value>
            </element>
            <element>
                <key>DSUBJECT</key>
                <value>DMA-IMA</value>
            </element>
            <element>
                <key>recipientDN</key>
                <value>uid=demo.user</value>
            </element>
            <element>
                <key>recipientLabel</key>
                <value>Demo User, 14699062,Department,AZO</value>
            </element>
        </map>
    </option>
</mproxyMessage>
```

What I need in return (for further processing) is the value between the `<uri>` tags (a file path), the `DSUBJECT` value, and the `recipientLabel` (only the number, but that's easy to split)

The URI seems to be quite simple  using:

```vb
Dim xml = XDocument.Load(file.FullName)
MsgBox("URI: " + xml.<mproxyMessage>.<attachments>.<attachment>.<uri>.Value)
```

But I'm stuck with the KEY/Value part

I have been looking at several code samples to do this, but none produced the result I was hoping for...

Is their someone who can provide me a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for the key/value elements using LINQ (untested code):

```vb
Dim dsubject = (
    From e In xml.<mproxyMessage>.<option>.<map>.<element>
    Where e.<key>.Value = "DSUBJECT"
    Select e.<value>.Value
).Single()
```

This looks for the `<element>` with the matching `<key>` value, and selects the associated `<value>` value.

Comment: Great!! Worked 'out of the box' !! Only need to find out how to make this error proof (some XML's don't have the dsubject tag), but this is a perfect starting point)

Comment: You can use `SingleOrDefault()` to handle cases where there is no match. It will return `Nothing` if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without specifying the root element:

```
    'to load
    ' someXML = XElement.Load(PATH HERE)

    Dim someXML As XElement = <mproxyMessage xmlns:ns2="com.cmp.mproxy.message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:mproxyMessage">
                                  <version>2</version>
                                  <receiver>
                                      <uid>az.local</uid>
                                  </receiver>
                                  <sender>
                                      <uid>test.sender</uid>
                                  </sender>
                                  <attachments>
                                      <attachment>
                                          <uri>C:\Inbox\2015-09-04\2cc403ace4984782bf5ae949e22a4d5b\VJ14699062340.ima</uri>
                                      </attachment>
                                  </attachments>
                                  <option>
                                      <map>
                                          <element>
                                              <key>OPTION_MEXI_OPTION</key>
                                              <value>DSUBJECT(DMA-IMA)DGIVENNAME(9803375)DSENDERID(144796) medidoc_formatrecipient : Demo User, 14699062,Department,AZO(recipient DN : uid=demo.user,null)</value>
                                          </element>
                                          <element>
                                              <key>DSENDERID</key>
                                              <value>144796</value>
                                          </element>
                                      </map>
                                  </option>
                              </mproxyMessage>

    Dim s As String = someXML.<attachments>.<attachment>.<uri>.Value
```

Comment: I think you haven't got my question right :).. Getting the <uri> value is no problem. It's getting  the value that corresponds with the DSUBJECT key, and the same for the recipientLabel key